# ESP8266 Wifi configuration

Tags: arduino, wifi, microcontroller, esp8266, feature-engineering

I had a Node MCU module as shown in the photo.
[My nodemcu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orVJR.jpg)

I had this tutorial from this link:[Tutorial link](https://youtu.be/PFP5jQGNErM)

I had a problem with WIFI Configuring which from the code I had online it should be working with the browser 192.168.4.1 as shown as below. But with my LoLin NodeMCU V3 I cant reach to the browser page and always show the connection has timed out. Can I know is it my NodeMCU module problem?
p.s.
The wifi connection work well with hardcoding but not WIFI configuration)
The Module i found there is slightly different from normal Nodemcu with a yellow component on it.
I used ARDUINO IDE to compile and upload.
[proper result with the browser for wifi configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Ah7.png)

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

//Variables
int i = 0;
int statusCode;
const char* ssid = "Default_SSID";
const char* passphrase = "Default_Password";
String st;
String content;


//Function Decalration
bool testWifi(void);
void launchWeb(void);
void setupAP(void);

//Establishing Local server at port 80 whenever required
ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(115200); //Initialising if(DEBUG)Serial Monitor
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Disconnecting current wifi connection");
  WiFi.disconnect();
  EEPROM.begin(512); //Initialasing EEPROM
  delay(10);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Startup");

  //---------------------------------------- Read eeprom for ssid and pass
  Serial.println("Reading EEPROM ssid");

  String esid;
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
  {
    esid += char(EEPROM.read(i));
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(esid);
  Serial.println("Reading EEPROM pass");

  String epass = "";
  for (int i = 32; i < 96; ++i)
  {
    epass += char(EEPROM.read(i));
  }
  Serial.print("PASS: ");
  Serial.println(epass);


  WiFi.begin(esid.c_str(), epass.c_str());
  if (testWifi())
  {
    Serial.println("Succesfully Connected!!!");
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Turning the HotSpot On");
    launchWeb();
    setupAP();// Setup HotSpot
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Waiting.");

  while ((WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED))
  {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(100);
    server.handleClient();
  }

}
void loop() {
  if ((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED))
  {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
      delay(1000);
    }

  }
  else
  {
  }

}


//----------------------------------------------- Fuctions used for WiFi credentials saving and connecting to it which you do not need to change
bool testWifi(void)
{
  int c = 0;
  Serial.println("Waiting for Wifi to connect");
  while ( c < 20 ) {
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
    {
      return true;
    }
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("*");
    c++;
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Connect timed out, opening AP");
  return false;
}

void launchWeb()
{
  Serial.println("");
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.print("Local IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.print("SoftAP IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());
  createWebServer();
  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");
}

void setupAP(void)
{
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.disconnect();
  delay(100);
  int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
  Serial.println("scan done");
  if (n == 0)
    Serial.println("no networks found");
  else
  {
    Serial.print(n);
    Serial.println(" networks found");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
      // Print SSID and RSSI for each network found
      Serial.print(i + 1);
      Serial.print(": ");
      Serial.print(WiFi.SSID(i));
      Serial.print(" (");
      Serial.print(WiFi.RSSI(i));
      Serial.print(")");
      Serial.println((WiFi.encryptionType(i) == ENC_TYPE_NONE) ? " " : "*");
      delay(10);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("");
  st = "<ol>";
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    // Print SSID and RSSI for each network found
    st += "<li>";
    st += WiFi.SSID(i);
    st += " (";
    st += WiFi.RSSI(i);

    st += ")";
    st += (WiFi.encryptionType(i) == ENC_TYPE_NONE) ? " " : "*";
    st += "</li>";
  }
  st += "</ol>";
  delay(100);
  WiFi.softAP("ElectronicsInnovation", "");
  Serial.println("Initializing_softap_for_wifi credentials_modification");
  launchWeb();
  Serial.println("over");
}

void createWebServer()
{
  {
    server.on("/", []() {

      IPAddress ip = WiFi.softAPIP();
      String ipStr = String(ip[0]) + '.' + String(ip[1]) + '.' + String(ip[2]) + '.' + String(ip[3]);
      content = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n<html>Welcome to Wifi Credentials Update page";
      content += "<form action=\"/scan\" method=\"POST\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"scan\"></form>";
      content += ipStr;
      content += "<p>";
      content += st;
      content += "</p><form method='get' action='setting'><label>SSID: </label><input name='ssid' length=32><input name='pass' length=64><input type='submit'></form>";
      content += "</html>";
      server.send(200, "text/html", content);
    });
    server.on("/scan", []() {
      //setupAP();
      IPAddress ip = WiFi.softAPIP();
      String ipStr = String(ip[0]) + '.' + String(ip[1]) + '.' + String(ip[2]) + '.' + String(ip[3]);

      content = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n<html>go back";
      server.send(200, "text/html", content);
    });

    server.on("/setting", []() {
      String qsid = server.arg("ssid");
      String qpass = server.arg("pass");
      if (qsid.length() > 0 && qpass.length() > 0) {
        Serial.println("clearing eeprom");
        for (int i = 0; i < 96; ++i) {
          EEPROM.write(i, 0);
        }
        Serial.println(qsid);
        Serial.println("");
        Serial.println(qpass);
        Serial.println("");

        Serial.println("writing eeprom ssid:");
        for (int i = 0; i < qsid.length(); ++i)
        {
          EEPROM.write(i, qsid[i]);
          Serial.print("Wrote: ");
          Serial.println(qsid[i]);
        }
        Serial.println("writing eeprom pass:");
        for (int i = 0; i < qpass.length(); ++i)
        {
          EEPROM.write(32 + i, qpass[i]);
          Serial.print("Wrote: ");
          Serial.println(qpass[i]);
        }
        EEPROM.commit();

        content = "{\"Success\":\"saved to eeprom... reset to boot into new wifi\"}";
        statusCode = 200;
        ESP.reset();
      } else {
        content = "{\"Error\":\"404 not found\"}";
        statusCode = 404;
        Serial.println("Sending 404");
      }
      server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      server.send(statusCode, "application/json", content);

    });
  }
}
```

I had tried several times with the code provided online but same results came out with the browser couldnt work.

Comment: What messages does the program output on the serial port?

Comment: check the string for whitespaces. use trim() to remove them

Comment: @romkey Hi, thks for the reply. The serial monitor shows the result same as the tutorial link i had provided. It just my browser couldnt generate.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to first connect to AP ElectronnicsInnovation and type "http://192.168.4.1" in browser address.
(https - by default - don't works).
I try your code on esp8266 and it works fine.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply and effort. Yes now works well but can i know will the wifi credentials lost and get erased if i upload a new code?

Comment: You can select "erase flash : all flash content" in arduino ide device settings.

Comment: Ok. It had work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

so I created this library for wifi provisioning, this is compatible with Arduino UNO WiFi and with Arduino Nano 33 IoT boards using WiFi101/WiFiNINA like module, I'm not sure about the support for your board, but you can check it out the library and find references to its dependencies here: **[InoWifiProvisioning](https://github.com/Suffro/InoWifiProvisioning)**.